# c# thread stopping without throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, service, threadpool

I have a long running thread in C# that is stopping without throwing an error. I have added additional try/catches to try to narrow it down but still no errors are being thrown. The thread is being set up as such:

```
loggingThread = new Thread(Log)
{
     IsBackground = true
};
loggingThread.Start();
```

Then the Log method is set up as such:

```
private void Log()
{
        log.Error("Logging started");
        stopLogging = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        try
        {
            while (!stopLogging.WaitOne(250))
            {
                try
                {
                    List<PublishValues> valuesToPublish = new List<PublishValues>();
                    List<RecentData> recentData;
                    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
                    {
                        recentData = session.Query<RecentData>().ToList();
                        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
                        {
                            foreach (var dataVal in recentData)
                            {
                                Historical lastHistory;
                                if (!LastHistories.ContainsKey(dataVal.Id))
                                {
                                    lastHistory = null;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    lastHistory = LastHistories[dataVal.Id];
                                }
                                if (dataValValueNeedsLogged(lastHistory, dataVal.SampleInterval))
                                {
                                    Historical hist;
                                    if (lastHistory != null && dataVal.Value == lastHistory.UnformattedValue)
                                    {
                                        var now = clock.Now;
                                        now.AddMilliseconds(-now.Millisecond);
                                        hist = lastHistory;
                                        hist.LastSampleUtcTime = now;
                                        hist.CheckValue = hist.CalcNt();
                                        session.Update(hist);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var now = clock.Now;
                                        now.AddMilliseconds(-now.Millisecond);
                                        hist = new Historical()
                                        {
                                            dataValId = (short)dataVal.Id,
                                            FirstSampleUtcTime = now,
                                            LastSampleUtcTime = now,
                                            StatusRaw = dataVal.Status,
                                            UnformattedValue = dataVal.Value,
                                            CountSamples = 1
                                        };
                                        session.Insert(hist);
                                        UpdateMrData(hist, session);
                                    }
                                    LastHistories[dataVal.Id] = hist;
                                    valuesToPublish.Add(Convert(hist, dataVal, DateTime.UtcNow));
                                }
                            }
                            tx.Commit();
                            if (valuesToPublish.Count > 0) eventPublisher.Publish<PublishValuesMessage>
                                    (new PublishValuesMessage(dataValValueChanges.ToArray()));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
```

}

No errors are being logged from either inside or outside of the loop. The manual reset event is never being set. No where in the application does it call thread.abort(). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Break the app in the debugger and look in the Threads view for where it's actually stuck.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error I would love to do that however we have only seen it do this after long running sessions such as 7-10 days.